# FOSUserBundle default route to direct to login form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Im playing with the FOSUserBundle and am struggling to work out how to setup the security.yml/routing.yml files so that the following rules apply:

1. www.domain.com/  - if unauthenticated directs to the login page which is using the default `www.domain.com/login`
2. www.domain.com/  - if authenticated directs to the /office/home controller.

**security.yml**

```
security:
  providers:
      fos_userbundle:
          id: fos_user.user_provider.username

  encoders:
      FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

  firewalls:
      main:
          pattern: ^/
          form_login:
              provider: fos_userbundle
              csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
              always_use_default_target_path: true
              default_target_path: /office/home
          logout:
              path:   fos_user_security_logout
              target: fos_user_security_login
          anonymous:    true

  access_control:
      - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/resetting, role: ROLE_USER }
      - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
      - { path: ^/office/, role: ROLE_USER }
      - { path: ^/office$, role: ROLE_USER }


  role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

**routing.yml**

```
home:
    path: /office/home
    defaults:
      _controller: etBundle:Office:home
```

Ive tried making an access control like this:

```
- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

but I think it creates some kind of loop problem with the other access control lines. and Ive tried a routing reference like this, but all sorts of odd stuff happened!:

```
default:
    path: /
    defaults:
      _controller: etBundle:Office:home     # <- to try to force it to authenticate
```

Many thanks

Comment: why won't you let a controller handling redirect in case of authenticated or unauthenticated users?

Comment: Yes I definitely could do that but I was wondering if it could be done just in the config files.

Comment: I think you can only force a redirect to login page for unauthenticated users via routing/security.yml. But the other way is not possible IMHO. You can only define the redirect page after successful login, but not the redirect for authenticated users when `/` is typed in directly

Comment: I guess what I want is for the whole site to be behind the firewall so any visitor has to login to get further.   I've just tried setting anonymouse to false but it creates some kind of loop

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `anonymous` has to be `true`. I think three firewall rules are enough, in exactly the following order: `- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`, `- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }`, `- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }`

Comment: awesome, that worked.  many thanks. if you put it in an answer Ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force redirect to login page for unauthenticated users via security.yml but the other way is only possible with custom redirection in controller. The only thing one can define in security.yml is the target page direct after login, but not redirect for logged in users when calling specific URL.

I think three firewall rules are enough to force login redirect, in exactly the following order:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```